# Display variable from Form1 to Form2

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I got confused for displaying a_hasil(Form1) to label21(Form2). Could someone please help me. Whats wrong with my code. Thanks
Form1:

```
Public Class Form1
Public a, b, c, d, a_hasil, b_hasil, c_hasil, d_hasil As Double

Public Sub button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles button1.Click

    a = Val(textBox1.Text)
    b = Val(textBox2.Text)
    c = Val(textBox3.Text)
    d = Val(textBox4.Text)

    a_hasil = (a * 1) + (b * 0.667) + (c * 1) + (d * 0.75)
    b_hasil = (a * 0.5) + (b * 0.778) + (c * 0.667) + (d * 1)
    c_hasil = (a * 0.625) + (b * 1) + (c * 0.778) + (d * 0.875)
    d_hasil = (a * 0.5) + (b * 0.889) + (c * 0.889) + (d * 0.875)


    Dim Form2 As New Form2
    Form2.stringpass = a_hasil
    Form2.Show()

End Sub
End Class
```

Form2:

```
Public Class Form2
Public Property stringpass As Double
Public Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    label21.Text = stringpass
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It is not very likely that the Form2_Load method will run, it is missing the `Handles` keyword.  Use the debugger to make sure, set a breakpoint.  Fix it by appending `Handles MyBase.Load` or by using the designer correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your load method was never called. Add Handles. The rest seems ok but I would ask that you limit your class variable to only what is needed.

```
Public Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
```

Change to

```
Public Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
```